# Can't try ubuntu 15 on my notebook

Tags: boot, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15 dualboot with win 10 on my MSI notebook. But when i boot into USB it show many error with the same code: CHED ERROR. I don't know what it mean. Could anyone help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

there could be many reasons for this. Make sure you wrote iso to usb the right:

sudo dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdc

/dev/sdc - path to your usb

way, check if secure boot is disabled in bios, to get into bios you need to press F2 right after your laptop starts, also check if you are booting with uefi or not. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank for your help. I did it but it didn't work. I write iso to usb by rufus for efi boot mode, turned off secure boot mode. Then I tried to change my boot mode to legacy, it worked. But then i can boot into window because my window use efi

Comment: Some distros are quite picky when it comes to uefi honestly I don't know how ubuntu deals with it since in mot using it for last couple of years,  after some googling I found this, hope it will help you 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Otherwise if this wont work you can always just have ubuntu installed in legacy mode and windows in uefi then obviously you wont be using grub2 but will have to manualy change in bios every time when you want to boot, not the best option more like last one